# How to retrieve time based data from Hbase Table

Tags: statistics, hbase, aggregation

HBase Table Structure:

Key, EventName, TimeStamp
My Key is UUID, timestamp is in long format. How can I retrieve data time interval data (say per hour) from this table structure.

Time interval is fixed (i.e. 0000 - 0100 HRS), (0100 - 0200 hrs) .... (2300 - 0000) HRS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**1.** If you don't know what the aggregation period would be or if you don't need realtime you can just scan the table and aggregate it client side (for tiny tiny datasets). In case your dataset is huge (it should be if you're using HBase) you'll need to set up a map-reduce to make use of parallelization (or use HIVE).

http://hbase.apache.org/book/mapreduce.example.html

---

**2.** If you need realtime you should consider implementing counters to pre-aggregate data based on the interval you need.

Introduction to counters: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/database-design/9781449314682/counters/id3238520

**Saving data:**

Think about this kind of row keys (allowing an infinite number of different EventTypes):

- 8 byte sharding key: somewhat like substr(md5(EventType),0,8)
- 4 byte POSIX timestamp for the 00:00:00 of the day (Integer.MAX_NUMBER - timestamp in order to write newest rows first).

Based on it you can have 25 columns (one for each hour + one for the full day), and give the whole family a TTL of 3 months (for pruning old data). That way, you can just increment the counter for the total column + the column which stores that interval.

Although there are other options (like including the day as part of the column) this model is both very flexible and powerful and works great for me.

**Requesting data:**

- To request the data for an interval of a known event you'll just have to do a get request.
- To request the last X days for one known event you'll have to do a scan with the start & stop row keys, which would be very fast. Every row will have the total column and the hourly columns.

**Drawbacks:**

- Pre-aggregation with counters requires 1 GET + 1 PUT which is more expensive than just puts.
- You'll get very hot regions if you have a lot of increments for the same type of event. In that case, it'll be a lot better to keep in memory counters (as atomic variables) and flush them to HBase every X seconds.